# IIS URL Rewrite Wildcards

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7, iis

I have some URLs as follows

- `http://localhost/wordpress/latest/joe/12`
- `http://localhost/wordpress/latest/bloggs/14`
- `http://localhost/wordpress/latest/thing/15`

I would like to redirect them to

- `http://localhost/wordpress/file.php?id=12`
- `http://localhost/wordpress/file.php?id=14`
- `http://localhost/wordpress/file.php?id=15`

So **latest** needs to be in the URL, then it could be anything, then a number

Any advice? I've tried this and although the test is fine, going to the URL doesn't work. I've even tried using a rewrite map but that doesn't work either.

By 'doesn't work' I mean the original URL stays on place.

```
<rule name="TEST" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="/wordpress/latest/(.*)/(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/wordpress/file.php?id=$2" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

**ReWrite Map**

```
<rule name="ArticlesRule">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{Articles:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule></rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="Articles">
                    <add key="/wordpress/latest/dfjkdskfjdklsf/12" value="/wordpress/?id=12" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture the desired id of the article using a condition, then you want to use that id you captured in the redirect action using {C:2} or Condition variable 2. Note that `REQUEST_URI` holds the path and query string while `PATH_INFO` just holds the path without query string. You probably want the path without the query string when capturing the article id.

```
<rule name="ArticlesRule">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/wordpress/latest/(.+)/([0-9]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/wordpress/file.php?id={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

If you want any other query string parameters to pass through to the redirected url, you could add `appendQueryString="true"` to your `<action>` element

If you want the clean urls to remain in the browser's address bar and hide the fact that file.php is being referenced, you would change your `<action type="Redirect">` to `<action type="Rewrite">`

Otherwise, this rule should redirect any /wordpress/latest/anything/anynumber to /wordpress/file.php?id=anynumber